# latex table layout problem

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

Hi Im having some trouble aligning the text in the second column of a two column table. The first column the text aligns the way i want but the seconds columns text is not positioning properly.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |m{7cm}|m{6cm}|}\hline
PHP & Hypertext Preprocessor \\[2ex] \hline
MySQL & Structured Query Language \\[2ex] \hline
HTML & Hypertext Preprocessor \\[2ex] \hline
JQUERY & JavaScript library \\[2ex] \hline
AJAX & Asynchronous JavaScript and XML \\[2ex] \hline
GUI & Graphical user interface \\[2ex] \hline
JavaScript & Hypertext Preprocessor \\[2ex] \hline
URL & Uniform resource locator \\[2ex] \hline
API & Application programming interface \\[2ex] \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}\newpage
```

[image: Result]

any help would be appreciated

Comment: unrelated to your problem but using `[h]` on its own is essentially an input error: latex will change it to `[ht]` to give itself a chance but still disallowing `p` floats makes it much more likely that the float goes to the end of the document.

Answer (score 6):

I assume that your "not positioning properly" problem is that the text in the second column is not vertically centered in the cell. Perhaps this is the reason for using the `m` column type? Since in your case each cell is short enough to fit in a single line, there is no reason to use `m` type. I guess that what you are trying to do is to have more vertical space inside the cells.

If this is the case, you can get the desired effect by redefining `\arraystretch`. The following MWE shows you how.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}\hline
PHP & Hypertext Preprocessor \\\hline
MySQL & Structured Query Language \\\hline
HTML & Hypertext Preprocessor \\\hline
JQUERY & JavaScript library \\\hline
AJAX & Asynchronous JavaScript and XML \\\hline
GUI & Graphical user interface \\ \hline
JavaScript & Hypertext Preprocessor \\ \hline
URL & Uniform resource locator \\ \hline
API & Application programming interface \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

**EDIT**: As suggested by cmhughes in a comment, I also removed the `center` environment and used `\centering` command. More info at [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables)

Comment: +1 but could you remove `center` and replace it with `centering` and link to [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2651)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the alignment. So what does `@{}m{0pt}@{}` stand for? `@{}` removes the empty space usually placed to separate the columns; hence having one on the right and left of `m{0pt}` creates non of those extra spaces. Notice that we do not have `|` after `@{}m{0pt}@{}` since we do not want the vertical rule of the column. Now the `m{0pt}` means that the column width is of zero length and thus non-existent. Essentially, what we have done is a phantom column just to help with the alignment.

The following should help in your ordeal:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|m{7cm}|m{6cm}|@{}m{0pt}@{}}
\hline
PHP & Hypertext Preprocessor & \\[2ex] \hline
MySQL & Structured Query Language & \\[2ex] \hline
HTML & Hypertext Preprocessor & \\[2ex] \hline
JQUERY & JavaScript library & \\[2ex] \hline
AJAX & Asynchronous JavaScript and XML & \\[2ex] \hline
GUI & Graphical user interface & \\[2ex] \hline
JavaScript & Hypertext Preprocessor & \\[2ex] \hline
URL & Uniform resource locator & \\[2ex] \hline
API & Application programming interface & \\[2ex] \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should provide an explanation why this helps. The OP will never make progress if they have to rely on examples only.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen updated answer for more clarification.

Comment: This looks like an array package bug to me

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It does. Probably contacting Frank Mittelbach should do the trick :)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Would you know what is actually causing this bug?

Comment: Well yes and no, `\\ ` adds struts to control the array row spacing (or to handle `\\[length]` and it's interfering with the `m` alignment. It's a _long_ time since I looked at that code.